# Add custom step before billing step in one page checkout in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I am new to magento.

In my site i have requirement to collect customer data on checkout process.

So i need this step to come up after login/guest checkout ( step 1 ) and before billing step.

All the data collected from customer in my additional step should be stored in DB as well in order.

Please help and guide.

Thanks